# How do I pass a variable to a stored procedure to update a row in another database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to get a value from one database for a customer and update another database with that value.

The procedure below works but I need to have it go through table2 and update every customer in table1 with a matching CustomerID. I hate to use the word loop through but as I said, I am very new to this and lost. I have watched videos, and tried to search with no luck. Can someone point me to a tutorial or tell me if I am trying to do something I shouldn't be?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.bhshSample
as 
BEGIN;
    update table1 set
        ptall = (
            SELECT TOP (1) nsma1_ans
            from table2
            where nsma1_code = 'ptall'
            order by nsma1_tm
        )
    where CustomerID = '4'
End;
```

In php, I would loop and do a select distinct CustomerID from table 2

then do the update using the variable I set but I can't seem to figure it out with stored procedure.

Comment: Note, don't quote numbers (`'4'` should just be `4`). You can update multiple rows in table1 by removing the `where` clause. But you don't appear to correlate your table2 `select` with your table1? Normally you would join in some fashion. Some sample data and desired results would go a long way to clarifying what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: To "pass a variable" to a procedure, you must create a parameter for that to be passed. That does not seem to be relevant here. The UPDATE statement has a form that will allow you to join the target table (to be updated) with another - that "another" table can be in your "other" database.

Comment: Thank you for the note on the quoting the numbers.  Can someone tell me how to format the answer?As for sample data:
Table1 has
'''Customer      ptall
1                     100
2                      120
3                     90
Table 2 has
custid    code   ans     tm  
1          ptall       101      08:00  
1          ptall       105      08:12  
1          APT         7         08:01  
2          APT        85        07:30  
Table1 should be  
Customer      ptall  
1                     105  
2                     120  
3                     97'''

Comment: Surround code or data with 3 backticks. If you click edit you can see the backticks I put around your code. Just add your data and do the same.

Comment: Thanks Dale. I am having a day. I'll see if I can find a tutorial on how to format the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery, like this:

```
update table1 set
    ptall = (
        SELECT TOP (1) nsma1_ans
        from table2
        where nsma1_code = 'ptall'
        and CustomerID = table1.CustomerID
        order by nsma1_tm
    )
```

Comment: Thank you!   I can see I have tons of reading to do.